# Convert the GMT date string to CTime or COLEDatetime

Tags: c++, mfc

How to Convert the GMT date string to CTime or COLEDatetime

"2011/06/01 3:20:20 GMT + 5:30"

Comment: Do u want to know if there is a built-in function? Or you are asking for code to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
   // current date/time based on current system
   time_t now = time(0);

   // convert now to string form
   char* dt = ctime(&now);

   cout << "The local date and time is: " << dt << endl;

   // convert now to tm struct for UTC
   tm *gmtm = gmtime(&now);
   dt = asctime(gmtm);
   cout << "The UTC date and time is:"<< dt << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[COleDateTime::ParseDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37t16xc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> The lpszDate parameter can take a variety of formats. For example, the following strings contain acceptable date/time formats:

```
"25 January 1996"
"8:30:00"
"20:30:00"
"January 25, 1996 8:30:00"
"8:30:00 Jan. 25, 1996"
"1/25/1996 8:30:00"  // always specify the full year,
                     // even in a 'short date' format
```

Comment: ParseDatetime wont take the GMT time string as parameter.

Comment: I would think that ["+5:30" is equivalent to "GMT + 5:30"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone); could you just filter the GMT substring _IFF_ the timezone offset (`[+-]0:00`) is present?